# Telethon get_dialogs function is taking forever

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to list all my account channels that i joined via Telethon. However, the `await client.get_dialogs()` function is taking forever with no response back!

I did even try the followign code as an alternative but the same thing is happening to  client.iter_dialogs() function

```
async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
    if dialog.is_channel:
        print(f'{dialog.id}:{dialog.title}')
```

Any ideas!!

Comment: Just to be sure, can you retrieve a single channel?

Comment: Please show your full code, I'm unable to reproduce this with 356 chats...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this problem when I have a huge number of chats in my account. Consequently, the function returned all chats. Maybe you should wait a bit longer.